# C# Set BlobProperties on CloudBlob Object For Testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure-blob-storage

I have a `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob blob;` object and I am calling the `blob.Properties` getter to get the blob's `BlobProperties` object. I want the `BlobProperties` object so I can read and store the `BlobProperties::LastModified` property into my own custom model.

I am unable to test this because I cannot construct a `BlobProperties` object with a non-null `LastModified` property. I cannot construct the expected object because there are no available constructors or setters to set the `LastModified` property. I only have a default and copy constructor available:

```
public sealed class BlobProperties{
    public BlobProperties();

    public BlobProperties(BlobProperties other);

    public DateTimeOffset? LastModified { get; }
}

var props = new Moq.Mock<BlobProperties>() // Error, cannot mock a sealed class
props.Setup(p => p.LastModified).Returns(DateTime.Now); // Unavailable since the class cannot be mocked

// Use the mocked BlobProperties as a return value for a mocked CloudBlockBlob 
var blob = new Moq.Mock<CloudBlockBlob>()
blob.Setup(b => b.Properties).Returns(props.Object);

...

// My custom model adapter
LastModified lastModified = blob.Properties.LastModified;
```

I am new to C# and I figured this could be solved by mocking with Moq, but the class is marked as `sealed` so it can't be mocked. Using shims is not an option.

So my question is...

How can I instantiate or override the getter so the `LastModified` property of a `BlobProperties` returns some non-null value?

I am using `Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob, Version=11.2.2.0`

See [BlobProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.blobproperties?view=azure-dotnet-legacy)

See [CloudBlob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblob?view=azure-dotnet-legacy)

Comment: If the below answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

BlobsModelFactory appears to be the answer. This type has a bunch of static methods with a set of optional parameters to create the BlobProperties instance.

```
var blobProperties = BlobsModelFactory.BlobProperties(contentType: "application/pdf");
var response = Substitute.For<Azure.Response<BlobProperties>>();
response.Value.Returns(blobProperties);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
        BlobProperties mockblobProperties = new BlobProperties();
        mockblobProperties.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(mockblobProperties.LastModified)).SetValue(mockblobProperties, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow);
        this.mockBlob.GetProperties().Returns(mockblobProperties);
```